# Working on the topic of homotopy equivalence and star-shaped polygon

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Given a function f such that:$$f:P \backslash \{p\} \rightarrow S^{1} \space via \space f(q) =\frac{q-p}{|q-p|} $$ given that P is a star-shaped polygon with respect to a point p in the interior of P.

I would like to show that f is a homotopy equivalence.

How should I tackle this statement? The definition of a homotopy equivalence is understandable but how can I apply it to prove that f is a homotopy equivalence.

I am new to the topic so any input will be greatly helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the restriction of $f$ to the boundary $\partial P$ of the polygon is a homeomorphism, since it is bijective continuous from a compact to a Hausdorff space.  Call $g$ the inverse of this map, sending $S^1$ homeomorphically to $\partial P$.

The composition $gf$ is the projection from the $P\,\backslash\{p\}$ to the boundary of the polygon $\partial P$.  First show this is homotopic to the identity - in fact, $\partial P$ is a deformation retract of $P\,\backslash\{p\}$.

The composition $fg$ is the identity by construction.

Comment: Thanks for your response but we have not discussed about boundary and probably wont talk about this in class. We know that a star-shaped region is contractable.

Comment: @Hugh You don't really need a fancy definition, by the boundary I just mean the set of line segments forming the polygon.